# Does this image show a series or parallel circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

Note bulbs are identical.

If I took out the wire in the middle, B and C would be in series.

Does adding the wire in the middle change anything? I think what would happen is the electrons travel to B, and then half of them go down the middle wire, and half go through C.

The ones that went through C would all pass through B previously, but only half of the ones that went through B would go through C.

Comment: Why would any of them move through C, when there is a perfectly conducting (ideally no resistance) wore straight back to the negative pole? This setup effectively removes all influence from C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this circuit a series or parallel circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212375/is-this-circuit-a-series-or-parallel-circuit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this case, no current is going to pass through $C$ because both of its terminals are connected to the same potential(-ve of the battery). This reduces to a simple circuit(neither series nor parallel). Remember we don't always have just those two kinds(sometimes none of them).